# I want to know about OpenGL in Android. I want to learn it.

Tags: android, opengl-es

Please, send me some demo application of `OpenGL` or tutorial of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.droidnova.com/android-3d-game-tutorial-part-i,312.html